# How to forward certain addresses only to another mail server with Postfix

Tags: postfix

For automatically handling bounce mail in an application, I need bounces sent back to certain adresses only to be delivered by pipe to the program which will manage these. There is two options :

- Forward those addresses to another SMTP server, which will pipe every received mail
- Pipe only these addresses on the main mail server

Is there any efficient and simple way to do one of those with Postfix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`# vi /etc/postfix/main.cf`

`virtual_alias_domains = yeswedeal.com`
`# virtual_alias_domains = example.com`
`virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`

`# vi /etc/postfix/virtual`

`rajat@yeswedeal.com rajat@ossc.com`

You can also implement a catch-all address i.e. email sent to tom@example.com and jerry@example.com should be forwarded to somewhereelse@another.domain.com

`@example.com         somewhereelse@another.domain.com`

Save and close the file. Type the following command to restart postfix:

`# postmap /etc/postfix/virtual`
`# service postfix reload`

Comment: Thanks. If I understand well, there is no way to transfer them to another server without having to alias the address(es) with another domain ?

Comment: yes your right :)